# in output width of four dynamic <li> of same class is not same

Tags: html, css

I had created four dynamic li which are sharing same class. But in the output the width of all the li is not same.You can simply try it in your browser.

Why is this happening? How to correct it?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.div-nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CC3399;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

.ul-nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.ul-nav li.space {
  background-color: black;
  width: 0.2%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-nav">
  <ul class="ul-nav">

    <li class="space"></li>
    <li class="space"></li>
    <li class="space"></li>
    <li class="space"></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue I'm seeing is that you're specifying a width for those li's as "0.2%", which just displays as a solid black line for me, even with content inside them.
Second, you may also be referring to the fact that there's more purple between the li's than there is to the left.  That is because you have a left and right margin set at 20px.  This means that the left-most li is 20 px from the left, and 20px from the right of the next li which has a 20px margin to its left.
Essentially you have 20 px to the left of the left-most li, 20px margin to the right of the right-most, and 40px (20 + 20) between them all.

Comment: sir i was asking that why these lines(0.2% <li>) are not of same width. ignore the margin things.as these are in %ge, u can check that one or two random lines disappear when you change width of your browser.

Comment: It's probably nothing more than a rendering issue...  no half-intelligent browser is going to expect an element with such an odd, miniscule width.  Why aren't you just creating a border with a 1 or 2 px width??  Curious on the purpose of the 0.2%...

Comment: i know i can use border,but its for some other purpose and i need to go through this way. what should i do to(except taking border) to take this percentage issue work fine?

Comment: The approach you're taking will be unpredictable and glitchy, like you're finding out.  In order to avoid the problem you're running into, you'll need to form a different approach.  0.2% is simply a negligible figure which leaves too much of the decision in the hands of the browser.  Even going with a set width of 1 or 2 px should yield the same functionality but look better and be 100% more predictable.

Comment: thanks mike for the tip. can u provide me a link from which i may know how browser take approximation of the width and also why the width in the above coding was different in the li's of same class? thanks in advance

Comment: Here's a brief article I found on sub-pixel rendering across various browsers:  http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

Answer (score 0):

That's because how the browsers calculate and rounded to whole pixels. 0.2% width means ~3.35px width.

*(The following is not calculated with the spaces inbetween, but it works the same)*

- The first li has to end at the 3.35px mark and is rounded to 3px
- The second li has to end at the 6.70px mark and is rounded to 7px (difference of 4px!)
- The third li has to end at the 10.05 mark and is rounded to 10px (difference of 3px)
- The fourth li has to end at the 13.40 mark and is rounded to 13px (difference of 3px)

If you would continue this sequence with even more lines, you'll notice that once every few lines the number is rounded up.

The best way to correct it is to work with fixed sizes. Like 2px or 3px.

Comment: sir i think you got my point. but i am not able to understand how browsers roundsup the percentage width.can u explain more or can u provide me with a helpful link?
Sir u said that second li has to end at a difference of 4px,this means it must be broader of all of them,but here the case is totally opposite,its thinnest of all the li.

Comment: Though I like your logic Maringo, I don't feel it's entirely accurate.  If you were talking .2em, then yes, you'd be at around 3.2px.  A percentage is relative to the browser/parent width and isn't predictable in application.
We're actually talking 0.2% and on a 1024px wide browser window that equates to about 2.05px (but again, it's all relative to the parent).

Comment: if all the li were having same parent,then why the width of few li differs from another?

Comment: Of course it depends on the width of your screen or the parent. The math itself might differ, but the logic is the same. It all has to do with the rounding up or down to whole pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add padding to the ul

```
.ul-nav{
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: sir i was asking that why these lines(0.2% <li>) are not of same width. ignore the margin things.as these are in %ge, u can check that one or two random lines disappear when you change width of your browser.

Comment: i don't know why the browser treating percentage  like this, you can use pixels instead of percentage (if you can). :)

Comment: actually i am making a Responsive Web Design and in it i need to take it in percentage, i.e. i am not using pixels..